# Optimize laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

hello there i am working on a project with 30000 records, i want to print all the records on the paper, but when excute the following command,it keeps on loading the data until it runs out of memory, keep in mind i am fetching data with three different tables using relations with user_id in common in all the tables, i want to optimize the query, so that i can print all the user records seamlessly

```
$users= \App\User::with(['withdarawals','deposits'])->get()->groupBy('id');
        dd($users);
```

Comment: Have you tried [chunking results](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results)?

Comment: paginate results

Comment: if i paginate the result, then how m i print all the users with one button click

Comment: Could the [cursor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#cursors) be a solution? Otherwise the `chunking` @PeterKrebs suggested will be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

The question is if the query is the problem or the size of the result. I suggest three things:

1. Debug what actually takes long and maybe increase php memory
2. Add table indexes for quicker database results
3. Chunk the stream and maybe add the data to a text file or something similar and try to print that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `groupBy()` call before the `get()` call or maybe you meant to call `keyBy('id')`, as `groupBy()` doesn't make much sense, because it's used to group arrays of multiple entries with the same value you pass to the method.